# Engineered hardwood repair help needed

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor

I have a piece of engineered hardwood that I am using to replace a damaged board.   The replacement piece has a slight bow in it.   Can I do a light cut on the back to reduce some of the bow pressure?

Comment: that would not do it, a steam roller will

Answer (score 1):

If the tongue/groove are there and intact, the force of the neighbors might hold the bow down.

Otherwise, cutting kerfs in the underside, perpendicular to the bow, can help. Go shallow and numerous, rather than a small number of deep cuts.